# the_content() - Getting formatted text

Tags: the-content

I'm using `the_content()` to display the content of a post in my theme, but unfortunately im getting plain text (with link and pics of course but the other are just plain text).

I want to get formatted text using `the_content()` or at least something else ?

Post on the Admin Panel:

[image: Editing the post]

And this is the post after publishing on the website:

[image: Published post]

Now as you can see while editing the post, making some headings and put some colors it's all fine, but after publishing the post on the website its all gone, just plain text!

What i want is to have the published post be the same as the post "while editing" (Formatted as i say).

---

### Update 2

After Deactivating a plugin (WP-PageNavi):

[image]

Still missing the heading and things.

---

### Fixed

Turns out i accidently deleted the ``` <h1>``<h2> ``` ....etc from the style.css, but i couldn't tell because of the WP-PageNavi plugin

Comment: what do you mean when you say "formatted text"

Comment: @MarkKaplun I Updated the post.

Comment: this looks like somewhere wpautop is disabled. If you don't remember having anything to do with it turn off as much functionality as you can until it works right (off all plugins).

Comment: I assume you checked tht it is not some major styling problem that replaces all `display:block` elements with `display:inline`

Comment: @MarkKaplun Looks like some styilings issues was because of a plugin, now what about the rest (Post Updated)

Comment: I only have `display: block;` for `.image` class